# Cannot connect to DB when setting up Codeception

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpunit, codeception

I am attempting to setup Codeception for the first time, however when I run `run --debug` I get a DB connection error, yet I cannot find where the configuration is to change this.

`vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco (confirmation)$ php vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run --debug`

`Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.9-dev
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.`

> [Codeception\Exception\Module]   (Exception in Db) SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [1045] Access denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' (using password:
>   NO) while creating   PDO connection

Comment: please post your db connection code.

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe I'm not familiar with Codeception. I cannot locate the Codeception DB configuration. Where is that found in the codebase?

Comment: I think its because of user 'ubuntu'(which does not exists). You can add the 'ubuntu' user through phpmyadmin and give that user no privilege and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the credentials to resolve this in the following files:

- tests/acceptance.suite.yml
- tests/functional.suite.yml

  `class_name: TestGuy
  modules:
      enabled: [REST, Db, ZF1, TestHelper, DbzHelper, GuzzleHelper]

      config:
          REST:
              timeout: 90
          Db:
              dsn: 'mysql:host=10.0.0.200;dbname=crmpicco_test'
              user: 'vagrant'
              password: 'vagrant'
              dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
              populate: true
              cleanup: false
          ZF1:
              env: 'test'
              app_path: 'crmpicco/application'
              lib_path: 'library'
              config: 'crmpicco/application/configs/application.ini'`